# Meteor Template Inside Script Tag

Tags: meteor

I want to fill a `script type="text/html` tag with a Meteor template.

So, this is an odd thing to do, I know. Half the reason I want to do this is because Cloud9 can't tell the difference between JS script tags and HTML script tags, and its syntax highlighting and tag-completion breaks when you try to write HTML in `script` tags. The other half of me is just curious to see if this is possible, because an ugly-as-sin workaround exists.

So this:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/html" id="test">
        {{> test}}
    </script>
</body>

<template name="test">
    <span>Test</span>
</template>
```

Produces this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="test">
    <!--label:YRgyaMH8-->
</script>
```

Anyone have a way to force it to render the template, instead of what looks like evaluate the name as a comment?

Comment: What's your final goal for this? Is it to have a template available for another JS component to take control of? I ask b/c there are other ways to pass templates from HTML to JS w/o having to embed it in a script tag. For example, take a look at this post:
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/10/11/simple-maintainable-templating-with-javascript/

Comment: My ultimate goal is to take advantage of the Cloud9 IDE features for writing HTML, to maintain templates that will be consumed by Knockout. Knockout has a method for using [external template engines](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), but it is cumbersome and sacrifices the advantages of writing the template as HTML in an IDE. Since I am already using Meteor, I thought it would be nice to use it "template" system to move normal HTML into the script tag, where Cloud 9 would normal break because its "smart" enough to know that stuff in a script tag is Javascript.

Comment: Have you considered foregoing Knockout and using Meteor for your binding needs? I'm not entirely familiar with everything Meteor and Knockout do, but it seems like they overlap on a lot of features.

Comment: @klamping Yes. I have used pure meteor for a project, but I do not like its template model. Using knockout to replace its backbone style template/controller system would be ideal for me.

Comment: Gotcha. Going to post a suggestion in the answers similar to what I wrote in my first comment. It may not solve it, but I figure I'll throw it out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting another answer b/c I'd like to keep my previous one just for the records. I think this approach will work better though.

Inside your html, you're going to define two sections. The first is where you're going to place your template code. It will go inside a comment inside a plain div tag. The second is where the template will be placed for Knockout to consume. It looks like this:

```
<template name="koTemplate">
    <div id="myTemplate">
        <span>Here is my template <a href="#">with children</a></span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/html" id="test"></script>
</template>
```

Then in your client JS code, you're going to add [a callback to run when the template is rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered)

```
Template.koTemplate.rendered = function () {
  // Get the first node, then get the content inside of it
  var templateHtml = this.firstNode.innerHTML;

  // Remove the element so it doesn't get rendered
  this.firstNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.firstNode);
  // another option is to surround the contents inside the template w/comments, but that loses syntax highlighting

  // Get the target node for placing the template in
  var templateNode = this.lastNode;

  // place the content from the original node to the target node
  templateNode.innerHTML = templateHtml;
};
```

This will basically get the content of the template, remove the template, then place it inside the script tags. The result will look like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="test">
    <span>Here is my template <a href="#">with children</a></span>
</script>
```

Comment: This will work, and I may do this for now, but it is a bit cumbersome. It will also mean the section getting altered with the template, since this code is in a reactive context. Ideally, I would like to find out what inside Meteor makes it render the comment inside the script tag, instead of the real template. Changing that would be a lot cleaner

Comment: agreed. Meteor documentation is still a bit lacking imo

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving away from using the script tag and instead use some other generic tag that Cloud9 won't treat as JS and Meteor won't fudge with. Using the example in my comment on the question, it would look something like this:

```
<div id="template">
  <!--<span>test</span>-->
</div>
```

And in your JS you would parse that:

```
var template = document.getElementById('template').firstChild.nodeValue,
    result = parseTemplate(template, values);
```

That's the basic idea. You'd have to convert it over to Knockout's template parsing after getting the result.

Comment: Knockout requires the template to be in a script tag.

Comment: It's a hack, but could you write the template to a new script tag before executing your Knockout commands?

Comment: Maybe. I'll have to dig into how Meteor stores the template.